# How would I detect if a POTS telephone is on hook?

Tags: circuit-design, opto-isolator

I've hooked up a plain old telephone directly to a 3W amplifier which happily plays music over the phone. It's the simplest thing on earth -- the 2 wire POTS connection is wired to the speaker output of a miniature "4-8ohm" amplifier.

The phone is not connected to the phone system. It will not have any ringing. It's just supposed to be like a hotline-when you pick it up, it plays MP3 files.

(The amp is really an Arduino with a music shield playing MP3 files.)

When the phone is on hook, it opens the circuit. How can I detect this with an input pin on the Arduino, without interfering with the audio while it is playing? I suspect that there is something I can do here with an optocoupler but it's a bit beyond my understanding.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIbpV7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Comment: Hi, (a) Can you please add a photo of the phone's internal wiring, on-hook switch, and PCB (if fitted)? (b) I was writing up an answer, but realised that I'd made an assumption, so I need to check: How *exactly* have you connected that amp to the phone? Have you connected the amp to *internal* phone connections which go directly to the phone's earpiece and the original earpiece wiring is disconnected? Or are you using the original 2-wire POTS connections, feeding the audio signal to those 2 wires, and all internal phone wiring is intact? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for asking! The amp is just going through the 2-wire POTS connection and the phone's internal wiring is intact.

Comment: @JoelSpolsky Do you still need this? Just seeing this and happy to take the time to write a full answer if you need it, but not if you have already moved on.

Comment: Well, I actually ended up taking apart the phone and directly connecting a second pair of wires to the physical hook switch. But that is because I scoured the internet and still couldn't find a decent explanation of how to recreate the phone company-style on-hook detection with just a single pair of conductors.

Answer (score 4):

A POTS telephone presents a DC resistance of about 180 ohms when it is off-hook, and open circuit when on-hook (the ringer bell is in series with a capacitor, blocking DC.)

Actual telephone lines use a sensing voltage of about 48V through a fairly high resistance. When the handset is lifted, the speaker and mic are connected across the line and draw current (20mA or so), and the voltage drops to 6 ~ 9V. The head-end senses this and changes over to the voice connection.

In your case you could use a smaller sense current - maybe just a 5K pull-up to Vcc - to detect switch closure (off-hook).

Here's a paper describing how POTS lines work: http://web.archive.org/web/20170830050151/https://hermonlabs.com/Products/innerData/pdf/Analog%20Telephony%20Overview.pdf

Comment: Thanks for replying! Yes, I am seeing something similar to that... actually my multimeter shows 765 ohms off hook but it's an old phone :) I'm still not visualizing the circuit I would need to build. I know I could simply treat the whole phone unit as a switch, and introduce my own current, but that current would interfere with the audio that is playing.

Comment: If you AC couple the audio that problem goes away. Notice this detail in the link I included. In your case, you might consider an audio transformer to do that, as the speaker is typically 32 ohm (that is, convert 8 ohm from your amp to 32 ohm, 1:4 ratio.)